# SQL SELECT STATEMENT IN ASP written in Frontpage

Tags: asp.net, sql, frontpage

Current select statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM vw_svc200_open 
WHERE (CUSTNMBR = '::CUSTNMBR::') 
ORDER BY ::sortcolumn::
```

This works and all is well.  But now I need to modify this select string to apply an extra filter.

```
SELECT * 
FROM vw_svc200_open 
WHERE 
  CASE 
     WHEN ::CUSTNMBR:: = 'ABC123' 
     THEN (CUSTNMBR =  '::CUSTNMBR::' AND CNTCPRSN = '::CNTCPRSN::') 
     ELSE (CUSTNMBR =  '::CUSTNMBR::') 
  END 
ORDER BY ::sortcolumn::
```

So basically I need to have my select filter on customer number and if customer number is ABC123 then I also need it to filter on Contact person...  The problem with the second SELECT (using the CASE statement) is that it throws an "error near =" on the THEN line.

The `::CUSTNMBR::` and `::CNTCPRSN::` are url string variables (What are those called again?).

Ex.

```
www.mywebsite.com/mypage.asp?Custnmbr=ABC123
```

Am I going to have to add some logic to the asp page (i.e. IF/Then) to set a variable, and then pass that variable to the *fp_sQry=* line?

Comment: The "url string variables" are called query strings.  You should not be passing these directly into your query, you may be prone to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Phillip O A safety layer would help you alot. +1 @Darren.

Comment: @DarrenDavies I didn't write the site, merely inherited it.  To structure it correctly I'd probably have to rebuild the whole thing, and I'm not that good a coder.  Only saving grace I've seen is that it won't let you get that page w/o logging in first... Thank you for correcting me on the query strings... as many times as I've used the phrase and seen it used, it just didn't want to come to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using nested if statements to set the select statement.